# Migrating over 3mill of data to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am trying to move mysql data to MongoDB. The record is over 3million rows. And every time it runs out of memory even after modifying my node start script

```
"scripts": {
    "debug": "node debug app.js",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=5120 --optimize_for_size --max_executable_size=5120 --stack_size=5120 app.js",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/bootstrap.test.js "
}
```

I tried using normal callback function and promises and still nothing.

**Whole Function**

```
var citiesInit = function(_setup) {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'WorldCities'
  });
  connection.connect();
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM thecities', function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err) {
      console.log("The error: ", err);
    }
    var cityData = [];

    rows.forEach(function(theCity){
      var data = {
        name: theCity.city,
        state_code: theCity.region,
        country_code: theCity.country,
        population: theCity.population,
        location: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [parseFloat(parseFloat(theCity.longitude).toFixed(4)), parseFloat(parseFloat(theCity.latitude).toFixed(4))]
        },
        max_latitude: parseFloat(parseFloat(theCity.latitude).toFixed(4)),
        max_longitude: parseFloat(parseFloat(theCity.longitude).toFixed(4)),
        min_latitude: parseFloat(parseFloat(theCity.latitude).toFixed(4)),
        min_longitude: parseFloat(parseFloat(theCity.longitude).toFixed(4))
      }

      var cityCreate = City.create(data);
      cityData.push(cityCreate);
    })

    console.log('The Saved row is: ', cityData.length);

    //With Promise
    Promise.all([cityData]).spread(function (cityData){
      if (cityData) {
        console.log(cityData.length);
        Setup.findOrCreate({slug: 'city', setup: true}, {name: 'City', slug: 'city', setup: true}).exec(function cb(err, setup){
            console.log("Cities initialized successfully");
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function (err){
      console.log(err);
    })

    //Without Promise
    City.create(cityData).exec(function cityCB(err, cities){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      if (cities.length) {
        console.log(cities.length);
        Setup.findOrCreate({slug: 'city', setup: true}, {name: 'City', slug: 'city', setup: true}).exec(function cb(err, setup){
            console.log("Cities initialized successfully");
        });
      }
    })
  });
};
```

I tried using `Streams` too

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM thecities')
    .stream()
    .pipe(stream.Transform({
      objectMode: true,
      transform:function(data, encoding, callback){
        var data = {
          name: data.city,
          state_code: data.region,
          country_code: data.country,
          population: data.population,
          location: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [parseFloat(parseFloat(data.longitude).toFixed(4)), parseFloat(parseFloat(data.latitude).toFixed(4))]
          },
          max_latitude: parseFloat(parseFloat(data.latitude).toFixed(4)),
          max_longitude: parseFloat(parseFloat(data.longitude).toFixed(4)),
          min_latitude: parseFloat(parseFloat(data.latitude).toFixed(4)),
          min_longitude: parseFloat(parseFloat(data.longitude).toFixed(4))
        }

        City.create(data).exec(function cityCB(err, city){
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }

          //if (city.state) { console.log(city.state) }
          callback();
        })
      }
    }))
    .on('finish', function(){
      connection.end();
      Setup.findOrCreate({slug: 'city', setup: true}, {name: 'City', slug: 'city', setup: true}).exec(function cb(err, setup){
          console.log("Cities initialized successfully");
          organizationInit();
      });
    })
```

Any help on how to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Consider using cursors on MySQL to fetch only a subset of the rows at a time: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-cursor.html

Comment: @DanArmstrong I can't see a way to use cursor in sails. So, I tried Streams which is more like a replacement for `Cursor` and the damn thing still ran out of memory.

Comment: I suspect the query call is still trying to load all into memory.  Try being explicit in your declare cursor and fetch.  This will mean looping yourself and fetching a batch, perhaps 1000 at a time, until you get fewer than 1000 records from the fetch.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports cursors to fetch smaller amounts of a query in batches to save memory:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-cursor.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fetch.html

Please see [How to loop through a table using a cursor in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990786/how-to-loop-through-a-table-using-a-cursor-in-mysql)